# Apollo Client: Send different headers relative to authentication/authorization

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I will often have an expired authorization token in my app.

I do not, however, want this error to block requests that do not require authorization. What is the work around?

I'd like to customize my headers for requests to simply view a page (which doesn't require token, so send with an empty header) and for requests to edit data (add token and allow error to block request).

An invalid token, with headers set like below for every request, is now blocking the simple fetching of open data:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql",
  request: operation => {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        'x-token': token || '',
      },
    });
  },
});
```